# Is it normal to reverse the placement of (adjective/noun) with (subject + verb)?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english, dialect

I've seen this type of sentences in Harry Potter books. I've made these up, but I'm sure Rubeus Hagrid or whoever talks like this:

> Tiring, those blokes are.

> Such a great man, Dumblodre is.

Why do they say that way? Is it some kind of dialect or what?

Comment: It's quite common in informal speech to emphasise a word or phrase by putting it at the beginning of the sentence. The implied meaning is "[They are] tiring" - "[He is] such a great man". It isn't part of any particular dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of construction is acceptable; phrases or sentences formulated this way can be understood with no ambiguity; they are correct English.

However, they are rarely used and, as far as I know, aren't characteristic of any particular dialect of English. The type of sentence you show is almost always formulated in the order

*subject* is *adjective*

So the effect of the alternative construction:

*adjective*, *subject* is

is that it generally sounds very strange, although unambiguous and grammatically fine.

So, in fiction we find this type of adjective-first or verb-last (or both) construction deliberately being used in the speech of a character to mark out that character as unique or different from others. The classic example is Master Yoda in [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars):

> Named must your fear be before banish it you can.

> Truly wonderful the mind of a child is.

> Difficult to see. Always in motion is the future.

> Powerful you have become, the dark side I sense in you.

Comment: It's a type of "inversion" (changing word order to something other than the English default *Subject + Verb + Object).* But note that some of your examples move the *Subject* to the final position, whereas others move the *Verb* to the end. And although *any* such inversion is by definition less common than the "default", not all variants are equal. So your second example (with the verb at the end) is *extremely* unlikely compared to the more common inversion *Truly wonderful **is** the mind of a child* (itself rare compared to the default *The mind of a child is truly wonderful*).

Comment: One very common context where you'll encounter this "literary device" is "historical / fantasy" writing such as the Harry Potter books. Partly because it's assumed (accurately or not, I dunno) that people really *did* speak more like [Yoda from Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda) centuries ago, but mainly because it's an established literary convention primarily intended to impart some element of "exotic other-worldliness" to a narrative.